# Is it safe to use a passphrase to seed fernet key generation?

Tags: cryptography, random

I have a cluster deployment that depends on a Fernet Key to secure some data. The deployment script generates the key with:

```
FERNET_KEY=$(python -c "from cryptography.fernet import Fernet; k = Fernet.generate_key().decode(); print(k)")
```

But following deployments will run that again and lose the first key, so I need to make that key generation deterministic. On the other hand, the deployment script is *mostly* stateless so I should avoid trying to read the key if it already exists.

I was thinking of using a passphrase parameter as seed to make the the Fernet key reproducible across deployments, but worried about the security implications. Is it safe to do that? Is there even a safe way to generate that key in a reproducible manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not safe at all. A passphrase would produce a deterministic key, but that would make this key vulnerable to brute-force and dictionary attacks. Besides, [`Fernet.generate_key()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/_modules/cryptography/fernet/#Fernet.generate_key) uses a CSPRNG (`os.urandom()`) which has an OS-specific randomness source and it does not accept a seed.

It is possible to create deterministic but strong keys, using a password-based KDF. Python's built-in `hashlib` library offers two such functions: [`pbkdf2_hmac()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac) and [`scrypt()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.scrypt). Both KDFs introduce a work factor (a good amount of CPU resources must be spent in order to produce a key) which makes brute-force/dictionary attacks practically impossible. I recommend scrypt because it costs CPU, memory and parallelisation resources, while PBKDF2 only consumes CPU resources.

Creating a Fernet compatible key with scrypt:

```
from hashlib import scrypt
from os import urandom
from base64 import urlsafe_b64encode

salt = urandom(16)
key = scrypt(b'password', salt=salt, n=16384, r=8, p=1, dklen=32)
key_encoded = urlsafe_b64encode(key)
```

The salt should be long and random; although it's not a secret, it must be unique for each password. 
The n, r, and p parameters determine the work factor (n=CPU/memory cost, r=block-size, p=parallelization). Those values can be increased depending on the OS - the key derivation process should take about 100 ms. Only the password is a secret value, the salt and n, r, p values can be stored or transmitted with the key.